# Find command returning wrong data

Tags: ubuntu, files, find

I am using this command to list all files that have been modified in the last day (or created)

```
find ./ -mtime 1 -ls
```

However it keeps returning files from 30th April when I am running the command just now (2nd May at 19:38)

Can anyone advise why this is occurring and / or give me a better command to use to find files modified or create in the last 24 hours period

Comment: `find . -mtime -1 -ls` or preferably `find . -mmin -1440 -ls`

Comment: That second one is much better for me.. and these both seem to work. Mysterious.

Post that second one as the answer so I can accept it as it worked for me

Comment: The way that `find` interprets the digits is not intuitive. From `man find` (slightly modified):  `When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last modified, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -mtime +1, a file has to have been modified *at least* two days ago.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `find` files that have been modified a certain days ago, it is better to use `-mmin` instead of `-mtime` as the latter will ignore any fractional part. So, 1 day 23 hours is also treated as 1 day.

From `man find`:

```
-atime n
         File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When find figures 
out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was  last  accessed, 
any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has 
to have been accessed at least two days ago.
```

In your case, the following will show the files that were modified in the last 24 hours i.e. 1440 mins:

```
find . -mmin -1440 -ls
```

Comment: beat me to it =)  so if find considers fractional part, `find ./ -mtime 0 -ls` should also do, because the modification date would be then 0 days 23 hours, right ?

Comment: @Serg: Yes..that would do too..

Comment: I thought it was doing something odd like that (treating 1day 23hours as 1 day). Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`-mtime N` means files whose age *A* in days satisfies *N* ≤ *A* < *N*+1. In other words, `-mtime N` selects files that were last modified between *N* and *N*+1 days ago. For example, `-mtime 1` selects files that were modified between 1 and 2 days ago. To select files that were modified in the last day (as in, the last 24 hour period), use `-mtime 0`.

`-mtime -N` means files whose age *A* satisfies *A* < *N*, i.e. files modified less than *N* days ago. Less intuitively, `-mtime +N` means files whose age *A* satisfies *N*+1 ≤ *A*, i.e. files modified at least *N*+1 days ago.

If you find these rules hard to remember, use a reference file instead.

```
touch -d '1 day ago' cutoff
find . -newer cutoff
```

(The syntax “1 day ago” requires GNU `touch`.)